# regular expression to find last letter and first letter of string

Tags: mysql

I need to find whether the last letter and first letter of the string is vowels (a,e,i,o,u). I want to do this in a regular expression.

```
select distinct city from station where city regexp '*.^[aeiou]$' and city regexp '^[aeiou].*';

First letter: ^[aeiou].*
last letter : *.^[aeiou]$
```

Here first letter identification is working fine but last letter regular expression is not working

Comment: That‘s most likely because the last letter is not preceded by a _literal_ `^` character ...

Comment: `^[aeiou]` and `[aeiou]$` should be enough here, you don’t need the rest that tries to check for arbitrary characters in between.

Comment: thanks. yeah, it's working. can you please give me details of each symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here first letter identification is working fine but last letter regular expression is not working

That’s most likely because the last letter is not preceded by a *literal* `^` character ...

`^` and `$` only anchor the pattern to the beginning/end, when they themselves appear at the beginning or end of the pattern (broadly speaking). For `*.^[aeiou]$` that is not the case for the `^` though, so in this place it means a *literal* `^` only.

`^[aeiou]` and `[aeiou]$` should be enough here - this demands that one of those vowel characters be found immediately at the beginning (`^`) resp. end (`$`). You don’t need the rest that tries to check for arbitrary characters in between.

Answer (score 2):

this code can check both cases together.

```
select distinct city from station where city regexp '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!